# Count and Data from Table in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5, query-builder

I am using Query Builder and here is my code in Laravel5

```
$users = DB::table('brand_customers')
            ->select('brand_id')
            ->where('mobile', $mobile)
            ->take(15)
            ->get();
```

I am limiting to 15 records but I am also looking for total count. Currently, I am getting count using this.

```
$users->count();
```

I tried the above code but no luck. How can I get both the data and count with the same query. Thanks.

Comment: replace the get() with count() and you get the count, if you want both, get the users (like you're doing) and just count($users)

Comment: If I want to limit 15 records and also want to get total counts, then how can i do that?

Comment: ... two separate statements? I think is the way

Comment: I think, this can be possible with count(*) as total with DB::raw. It was possible in CodeIgniter.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Here is the answer to this question. 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223512/how-to-select-count-with-laravels-fluent-query-builder][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223512/how-to-select-count-with-laravels-fluent-query-builder

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate statements like:

```
$users = DB::table('brand_customers')
        ->select('brand_id')
        ->where('mobile', $mobile);

$count = $users->count();
$users = $users->take(15)->get();
```

Comment: I don't want to create two separate statements.

Comment: Here is the answer to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223512/how-to-select-count-with-laravels-fluent-query-builder