# Laravel Select Count Where Query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have Orders table and status column in my DB, the status is stored as [1,2,3,4] which is corresponding at frontend to [issued, pending, on thew ay, delivered] now I need to get the count of each status between 2 dates,

Please Note : I need the count of each status like,

issued : 80
pending : 50
on the way : 20
delivered : 170

I tried below code but don't no how to accomplish my needs

```
$account = DB::table('order')
                    ->whereBetween('created_at',[$fromdate, $todate])
                    ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(order.status) as total'))
                    ->get();
                    return response()->json($account,200);
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223512/how-to-select-count-with-laravels-fluent-query-builder

Comment: this answers dont match my needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$account = DB::table('order')
    ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(order.id) as total'),'status')
    ->whereBetween('created_at',[$fromdate, $todate])
    ->whereIn('status',[1,2,3,4])
    ->groupBy('status')
    ->get();

return response()->json($account,200);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('order')
    ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total')
    ->whereBetween('created_at',[$fromdate, $todate])
    ->groupBy('status')
    ->get();
```